# How to query MongoDB using aysnc/await?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

So I'm following a course on Udemy to learn web development using **Node/Express/MongoDB** and using **mongoose** to interact with the database.

I have reached a lecture where the instructor started explaining on *how to query the database* so here created a mongoose model and named it `Tour` and in a controller file he wrote this to query the data that we already imported like this:

```
exports.getAllTours = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const queryObj = { ...req.query };
        const exludedFields = ["sort", "limit", "page", "fields"];
        exludedFields.forEach(el => delete queryObj[el]);

        const query = Tour.find(queryObj);

        const tours = await query

        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                tours: tours
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            message: err.message
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above we used the handler function `getAllTours` to get all the tours which by the way it handles this route `app.get('/api/v1/tours/')`.

At the beginning of the lecture the code for the query was like this: `const query = await Tour.find(queryObj);` and then he removed the `await` keyword to look like the code above were he included the `await` keyword for the tours object later.

The instructor explained this by saying that if we used the await on the query like this `const query = await Tour.find(queryObj);` then the code will execute immediately and then we would not be able to chain other methods on the query like `.where()` or .`equals()`.

**I need someone to explain these questions for me:**

1. why would the code execute immediately if we used `await`?
2. the `Tour.find()` does need time to query the database, so I think we should add `await`, shouldn't we?

Answer (score 0):

The `Tour.find()` returns a promise (is an async call), adding the **await** in front of it will wait until the promise is resolved and return it results.

If you want to do a **where()** after you do the **find** you can do it after the query is executed since you will have the results in that object in your case the **tours** object.

Honestly I prefer doing `const tours = await Tour.find()` you save a varaible that is kinda of innecesary, just is necesary if you want to catch an error of the promise or something like that.

In your case you using a try catch so the error will go to the catch block if something happens with the query (connection issues or other problems)

Comment: Tour.find() needs time to execute so I think we must add await before right? in the code above he simple removed it why? I don't want to chain methods like .where() or .equal() to it I simple surprised that he removed the await.

Comment: Yes, Tour.find() takes some time to go to the database and retrieve the data. so the await Tour.find() will be ok. If this anwser your question please mark it as answered :)

Comment: thats the whole point Diego, he removed it! how?

Comment: The query variable has the promise returned by the Tour.find() when you do await query, what you doing is waiting that the query end and return it result, just use a different variable